# Hide Images from Sources tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a webpage with images. The images have some information about my project. Hence I made them non-downloadable but I can find all the images present in the `Sources` tab ( Inspect > Sources ). Please provide me with a way to hide images even in sources tab. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to hide images from the sources tab because any images displayed on a website are loaded as resources, which the sources tab is designed to display. If you really don’t want the other to use your image, maybe you can add a copyright notice or watermarking.